# Pontos de recompensa opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: php, opencart

Tenho uma loja em opencart 2.0.3.1

Estou vendendo produtos e a cada 5 reais gasto o cliente ganha 1 pontos.

Quando o cliente vai utilizar esses pontos e ele escolhe retirar na loja o produto que ele comprou com os pontos o valor desta compra pode resultar em 0
.
Ai que esta o problema quando o valor é 0 ele não pula a parte do checkout nem exibe nenhuma informação ou opção que o pedido já esta ok para prosseguir.

Simplesmente a loja mostra o pag seguro como forma de pagamento sem o preço e não deixa finalizar o checkout por este motivo.

Alguém já passou por isso ou sabe como eu adiciono uma forma de pagamento para quando o valor for 0 ou negativo em específico?

Comment: Como que o valor da compra seria zero se o usuário selecionou um produto? Você não consegue enviar o valor real do produto para o PagSeguro, junto com um desconto de mesmo valor?

Comment: pode ser 0 pois o cliente pode comprar produto com pontos

Answer (score -2):

Neste caso habilite o meio de pagamento Pagamento Grátis - ele só aparece quando o valor da compra é igual a zero.

--- Spam Removido ---

Comment: Aqui não é o melhor lugar pra divulgar seus serviços.

Comment: vou tentar. Outra duvida é como faço o pag seguro não aparecer quando o valor da compra é 0 ?

Comment: deveria deixar ele postar pois eu solicitei o suporte da empresa em questao

Comment: Vai contra as regras do site, @JasarOrion

Comment: @JasarOrion O suporte da empresa em questão deve ser feito pelos canais da empresa em questão.

Comment: ok sem problemas.